# How to load link on button click from string in android

Tags: android, parsing, webview

I have an Rss feed that i have parsed and on the item click it opens a new window with a Title, and Description and a button to click to view a link it parses from the item.  How do i make that link open with the button click into the browser.  I think i'm close to making it work because i get the browser to launch but it doesn't input my url from the string.  here is the code i'm working with

```
 public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_GUID = "guid";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);
    String uriUrl = in.getStringExtra(KEY_GUID);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(cost);
    lblDesc.setText(description);

Button devo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
devo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(KEY_GUID));
                internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
                internetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(internetIntent);

    }
});
}

 }
```

here is the code for the xml parser that should be sending the information to this activity, maybe i have something wrong here or maybe its not sending the proper values for the url

```
 public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.cpcofc.org/devoapp.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "item";
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_GUID = "guid";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
        map.put(KEY_GUID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_GUID));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e,KEY_LINK));


        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_DESC, KEY_NAME, KEY_COST}, new int[] {
                    R.id.desciption, R.id.name, R.id.cost});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    Collections.reverse(menuItems);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(menuItems.get(position).get(KEY_GUID));

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_GUID, uriUrl);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
 }
```

log for crash

```
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371): java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:420)
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:410)
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:382)
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.SingleMenuItemActivity$1.onClick(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:49)
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 20:38:26.886: E/AndroidRuntime(28371):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this log cat is for the first answer that is given and the changes done from that first answer

Comment: I see   static final String KEY_GUID = "guid", so, what mean Uri.parse(KEY_GUID)?

Comment: guid is the node in the xml that i have parsed that contains the link.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the right is:

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

private String mUrl = "";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    mUrl = in.getStringExtra(KEY_GUID);

    ....
devo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mUrl));
                internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
                internetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(internetIntent);

    }
});
}

 }
```

if getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_GUID) get a real url like "http://www.google.cl"

Comment: still crashing it, would you like log cat info

Comment: loL, I saw your XML parser and you send the url as a uri in the extras... pass it as String : Uri uriUrl = menuItems.get(position).get(KEY_GUID);
in.putExtra(KEY_GUID, uriUrl);

Comment: added the log for the crash to see if that helps any

Comment: where do i need to do this at?

Comment: @RodrigoAmaroReveco I'm curious as well.  Where does that need to be passed as string?  Perhaps you could give all info when suggesting a fix, or at least respond to follow-up questions.